Copy a char** to char* passed as function param
I made a personal function to change the file extension in C.
One, maybe more then one, problem is that I don't know how copy source character to buff variable. I get a segmentation fault, see example:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_dot_pos (const char* str, int* size)
{
    int npos = 0;
    int n = 0;
    for (int x = 0; *str != '\0'; x++)
    {
        if (*str == '.')
            npos = x;
        str++;
        n++;
    }
    *size = n;
    return npos;
}

int replace_ext (const char* source, int source_size, int dot_pos, const char* new_ext, char** buff)
{
    *buff = malloc(source_size+1);
    int x = 0;
    int go_on = 1;
    while (go_on)
    {
        if (x != dot_pos)
        {
            **buff = *source; // sg fault here :(
            *buff++;
            source++;
            x++;
        }
        else
        {
            for(; *new_ext; new_ext++)
            {
                **buff = *new_ext;
                *buff++;
                x++;
            }
            *buff = '\0';
            go_on = 0;
        }
    }
    return x;
}


int main()
{
    const char* str1 = "/bar/foo/buz/rolitas.mp3";
    int size = 0;
    int npos = get_dot_pos (str1, &size);
    char* str2;
    replace_ext (str1, size, npos+1, "ogg", &str2);
    printf("Before: %s\n", str1);
    printf("After: %s", str2);
    free (str2);
    return 0;
}

Any ideas?

This is a very convoluted way to do this. One issue is that by modifying *buff inside your function, you are modifying str2 in your main, because **buff is a pointer to str2. As a result, by the time your function finishes running, str2 is pointing to a null character. You're already incrementing x, use it as an index into your strings like *buff[x] = source[x].

You're not even using the return value. Why not make the function return the new string instead? Or at least keep it in a local variable and assign the pointer at the end. Dealing with double indirection everywhere makes for ugly code and invites mistakes. Note also that if the new extension is larger than the old one, your program will overflow your memory buffer. It also doesn't handle a file without extension, and could instead pick up a directory with an extension. Using strrchr, memcpy and strncpy here would make the code simpler and easier to follow: https://godbolt.org/z/TdP31qnT3

Your major problem is with the *buff++ lines, these aren't doing what you think.  Look at the order of operations, ++ posfix increment is done first, then * dereference.  This means that buff is incremented, then dereferenced.  The dereference is entirely useless since nothing is using it.  You should have gotten a warning about this.  If not, turn your warning level up:
<source>:29:13: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
   29 |             *buff++;
      |             ^~~~~~~

Because buff was incremented in the first iteration, the second time around the loop, buff points to memory you don't own, and trying to dereference that location with **buff = *source invokes undefined behavior and explodes.
You can fix that particular problem by using parenthesis, change that to (*buff)++ to dereference the memory location you do own, then increment that position.
The next problem is *buff = '\0';.  Based on your usage of '\0' it looks like you're trying to NUL-terminate the string.  However, *buff is a char* type, the char literal '\0' is an int 0, which is getting interpreted as a NULL pointer (kind of surprised this doesn't throw a warning), so now everything you've done with buff is now nullified, as you've lost the pointer to your malloced memory causing it to leak.  You're essentially doing:
*buff = malloc(...);
...
*buff = NULL;

Then back in main, you try to print str2 which is now NULL, try to free it, and bad things happen.
The easiest fix is mentioned in the comments.  Instead of incrementing buff each time, simply use your x variable as an offset along with parenthesis to make sure the dereferencing happens first.  Those lines change to:
(*buff)[x] = *source;
...
(*buff)[x] = *new_ext;
...
(*buff)[x] = '\0';

Now back in main, str2 points to your replacement string.  However, I echo everyone else's warnings that this approach is convoluted and suffers from some potential corner case problems.

Thanks for explaning one of my problems. Question: What is a corner case problem?

@Joel corner cases are use cases that aren't considered "normal" behavior, yet are still perfectly valid/possible to occur, and they must be accounted for and handled appropriately to have robust and reliable code. Nearly all software exploits are rooted in some corner case the programmer didn't consider, like checking to make sure user input can fit within your buffer (buffer overrun exploits), or making sure it's sanitized to a particular format (SQL injection).

@Joel In your particular case, one issue already pointed out I believe, your replace_ext function assumes the replacement extension will always be the same length as the source extension with *buff = malloc(source_size+1);. What if I passed in "docx" instead of "ogg"? You haven't malloced enough space to handle that, and will overwrite your memory space by 1, invoking UB. Worse yet, what if I'm a malicious actor, I could pass in any string I wanted, potentially containing malicious code, hijack your program, and cause real trouble.

Your code seems way too complicated, and the issues with it have already been addressed in other comments. I would suggest to use built-in C-library functions to streamline it, like so:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    const char *filename = "/bar/foo/buz/rolitas.mp3";
    
    // Get a pointer to the character in front of '.'
    const char *dotPos = strrchr(filename, '.') + 1;
    // Allocate space for the new filename
    char *newFilename = malloc(dotPos - filename + strlen("ogg") + 1);
    // Copy the filename up to the dot
    strncpy(newFilename, filename, dotPos - filename);
    // Append the new extension
    strcat(newFilename, "ogg");
    
    printf("Before: %s\n", filename);
    printf("After : %s\n", newFilename);
    
    free(newFilename);
    return 0;
}

Edit: To answer Joel question
int main()
{
    const char *filename = "/bar/foo/buz/rolitas";
    const char *newExtension = ".ogg";
    
    const char *dotPos = strrchr(filename, '.');
    int newFilenameLength = (dotPos ? (dotPos - filename) : strlen(filename)) + sizeof(newExtension);
    char *newFilename = (char *)malloc(newFilenameLength + 1);
    strncpy(newFilename, filename, newFilenameLength - sizeof(newExtension));
    strcat(newFilename, newExtension);
    
    printf("Before: %s\n", filename);
    printf("After : %s\n", newFilename);
    
    free(newFilename);
    return 0;
}

Edit: Fix Dúthomhas suggestion
int main()
{
    const char *filename = "/bar/foo/buz.quux/rolitas";
    const char *newExtension = ".ogg";
    
    const char *lastDotPos = strrchr(filename, '.'); // Find the last dot
    const char *lastSlashPos = strrchr(filename, '/');   // Find the last slash
    const char *dotPos = (lastDotPos > lastSlashPos ? lastDotPos : 0); // Choose dot after the last slash
    
    int newFilenameLength = (dotPos ? (dotPos - filename) : strlen(filename)) + sizeof(newExtension);
    char *newFilename = (char *)malloc(newFilenameLength + 1);
    strncpy(newFilename, filename, newFilenameLength - sizeof(newExtension));
    strcat(newFilename, newExtension);
    
    printf("Before: %s\n", filename);
    printf("After : %s\n", newFilename);
    
    free(newFilename);
    return 0;
}


I’m not the only one who makes mistakes. filename = '/bar/foo/buz.quux/rolitas";

@Dúthomhas sorry but I didn't understand your comment.
If the issue is that the filename may contain '.' within the path, the strrchr still works:
"The strrchr() function returns a pointer to the last occurrence of the character c in the string s." - from the manual.
If the issue is that the filename doesn't have an extension, my advice is to check the return value of the strrchr and deal with that type of scenario, making it more robust according to your needs.

@artur, one question: how can I only append the "ogg" if the input file doesn't have a file extension?

@Joel if the filename doesn't have an extension, the strrchr function will return NULL as it is not able to find the last occurrence of the character '.'. If this happens, you want to allocate space for the whole filename + '.ogg' and then copy the filename. Note that you can also do this in one go, using strdup(). After that, use strcat() to append to end of the new string the '.ogg'.

I’m sorry, this code is broken and OP is treating it as correct. I have already given the minimal case that breaks it.

@Dúthomhas that's an unusual file path, but it should work now.

/bar/foo/.quux, /bar/foo/.., /bar/foo/. /bar/foo/, .quux, a.c, etc. Not as easy as it looks, no?

Okay, so, this kind of stuff is never as simple as it looks. I proved that by posting a broken answer a few days ago. (I tried to be tricky and made a mistake and tripped over one of C’s main syntax flaws, despite 20+ years of experience with it. We can all make dumb mistakes!)
dots
The hard thing is finding and identifying the location of a file extension in the last component of a path. There are four general cases:

hello.txt — “normal” filenames
hello. — filenames with an empty extension
.hello — dotfiles and filenames without an extension
.. — special names that cannot be modified
The empty string (which SO’s markdown won’t let me show to you).

Notice that that list handles weird names like hello...world.txt, since we are looking only for the last dot. It also handles hello...world, since it is fair to accept .world as that file’s extension.
path separators
Each of those cases may be preceded by a valid path using either / or \ as separator. (Other systems exist using other weirdo separators, but we’ll pretend they don’t going forward.)
caveats
Keep in mind that no matter how careful we are, there will always be stuff that can break us. The best we can do is verify that it works on the systems we want for the filenames we want, and not break in unexpected ways when we get weird or nonsense input.
⟶ For example, on Windows C:foo.x is also a valid path. Conveniently for us, anything left of the : cannot have a ., so we can pretend it isn’t a special case and therefore ignore it.
find the file extension
const char * get_file_ext( const char * path );
// Function
//   Find the file extension of the last component in `path`.
//
// Arguments
//   path • A valid file path. Must not be NULL.
//
// Returns
//   Pointer to '.' in the last component of `path` if it has an extension.
//   Pointer to '\0' if the last component of `path` does not have an extension.
//   NULL if the last component of `path` is empty, ".", or "..".

#include <iso646.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char * get_file_ext( const char * path )
{
    const char * sep = NULL;
    const char * dot = NULL;
    const char * pos = path;

    // Find last path separator and last dot, if any
    for (;  *pos;  ++pos)
        switch (*pos)
        {
            case '.':            dot = pos; break;
            case '/': case '\\': sep = pos; break;
        }

    const char * filename = sep ? sep+1 : path;

    // No filename --> cannot change extension
    if (filename == pos) return NULL;

    // No dot --> append an extension if desired
    if (!dot) return pos;

    if (filename == dot)  // special filenames begin with '.'
    {
        // "." is a special name --> cannot change extension
        if (filename+1 == pos) return NULL;

        // Dotfile without extension --> append an extension if desired
        return pos;
    }

    // ".." is a special name --> cannot change extension
    if ((pos-filename == 2) and (*filename == '.')) return NULL;

    // Everything else is a filename with an extension --> return extension's dot
    return dot;
}

Notice that the code only makes a single pass over the input path. This might actually be less efficient than simply using strrchr() three times to find the last ., /, and \. That would be something worth profiling.
With this you can now find the file extension of the last component of the path and also know:

can it be changed?
does it have an extension?

Notice also that filenames like ... are not special, and therefore return an empty extension (filename:.., extension:.)!
change the file extension
Now we can write code to change a file’s extension. There are two ways of dealing with string data in C: modify-in-place and dynamic-duplication. Joel’s code has asked for the second, but as both functions are small I might as well post both.
char * change_file_ext( char * path, const char * extension );
// Function
//   Change the file extension of the last component in `path`, if possible.
//   The extension is not changed if get_file_ext() returns NULL.
//
// Arguments
//   path • A valid path. Must not be NULL. 
//     Must have sufficient space to accommodate the new extension.
//     For example:
//       "filename.x" (11 chars)  -->  "filename.txt" (13 chars)
//       Hence, `path` must be at minimum 13 characters long.
//
//   extension • The new extension value. Must not be NULL.
//     May or may not begin with a dot '.'.
//     If empty, this function REMOVES the file extension.
//     Examples:
//       "filename.txt", ".dat"  -->  "filename.dat"
//       "filename.txt", "dat"   -->  "filename.dat"
//       "filename.txt", "."     -->  "filename."
//       "filename.txt", ""      -->  "filename"
//
// Returns
//   `path` if the file extension was changed.
//   NULL otherwise (because get_file_ext() returned NULL).

char * alloc_new_file_ext( const char * path, const char * extension );
// Function
//   Change the file extension of the last component in `path`, if possible,
//   and return the new `path` as a newly-allocated string.
//
//   This otherwise works just like change_file_ext().
//
//   Don't forget to free() the result.
//
// Arguments
//   Same as change_file_ext(), which see.
//
// Returns
//   A duplicate of `path` with the last component’s file extension changed.
//   NULL if get_file_ext() returns NULL.
//   NULL on allocation failure.

char * change_file_ext( char * path, const char * extension )
{
    char * p = (char *) get_file_ext( path );
    if (!p) return NULL;
    
    *p = '.';
    strcpy( p + (*extension and (*extension != '.')), extension );
    return path;
}

char * alloc_new_file_ext( const char * path, const char * extension )
{
    const char * p = get_file_ext( path );
    if (!p) return NULL;

    size_t n = p - path;
    char * result = malloc( n + 1 + strlen( extension ) + 1 );
    if (!result) return NULL;

    strncpy( result, path, n );
    result[n] = '.';
    strcpy( result + n + (*extension and (*extension != '.')), extension );
    return result;
}

Don’t forget to #include the right headers (listed above) and compile with a version of the standard that isn’t more than 25 years old.
test suite
In case you are curious, here it is.
test( "hello/world.cpp", ".h", "hello/world.h" );
test( "hello/world.cpp", ".x.y.z", "hello/world.x.y.z" );

test( "hello/wor.ld.c", ".hpp", "hello/wor.ld.hpp" );
test( "hello/wor.ld.c", "hpp",  "hello/wor.ld.hpp" );
test( "hello/wor.ld.c", ".",    "hello/wor.ld." );
test( "hello/wor.ld.c", "",     "hello/wor.ld" );

test( "hello/world..c", ".hpp", "hello/world..hpp" );
test( "hello/world..c", "hpp",  "hello/world..hpp" );
test( "hello/world..c", ".",    "hello/world.." );
test( "hello/world..c", "",     "hello/world." );

test( "hello/world.c", ".hpp", "hello/world.hpp" );
test( "hello/world.c", "hpp",  "hello/world.hpp" );
test( "hello/world.c", ".",    "hello/world." );
test( "hello/world.c", "",     "hello/world" );

test( "hello/world..", ".hpp", "hello/world..hpp" );
test( "hello/world..", "hpp",  "hello/world..hpp" );
test( "hello/world..", ".",    "hello/world.." );
test( "hello/world..", "",     "hello/world." );

test( "hello/world.", ".hpp", "hello/world.hpp" );
test( "hello/world.", "hpp",  "hello/world.hpp" );
test( "hello/world.", ".",    "hello/world." );
test( "hello/world.", "",     "hello/world" );

test( "hello/world", ".hpp", "hello/world.hpp" );
test( "hello/world", "hpp",  "hello/world.hpp" );
test( "hello/world", ".",    "hello/world." );
test( "hello/world", "",     "hello/world" );

test( "hello/.wor.ld.c", ".hpp", "hello/.wor.ld.hpp" );
test( "hello/.wor.ld.c", "hpp",  "hello/.wor.ld.hpp" );
test( "hello/.wor.ld.c", ".",    "hello/.wor.ld." );
test( "hello/.wor.ld.c", "",     "hello/.wor.ld" );

test( "hello/.world..c", ".hpp", "hello/.world..hpp" );
test( "hello/.world..c", "hpp",  "hello/.world..hpp" );
test( "hello/.world..c", ".",    "hello/.world.." );
test( "hello/.world..c", "",     "hello/.world." );

test( "hello/.world.c", ".hpp", "hello/.world.hpp" );
test( "hello/.world.c", "hpp",  "hello/.world.hpp" );
test( "hello/.world.c", ".",    "hello/.world." );
test( "hello/.world.c", "",     "hello/.world" );

test( "hello/.world..", ".hpp", "hello/.world..hpp" );
test( "hello/.world..", "hpp",  "hello/.world..hpp" );
test( "hello/.world..", ".",    "hello/.world.." );
test( "hello/.world..", "",     "hello/.world." );

test( "hello/.world.", ".hpp", "hello/.world.hpp" );
test( "hello/.world.", "hpp",  "hello/.world.hpp" );
test( "hello/.world.", ".",    "hello/.world." );
test( "hello/.world.", "",     "hello/.world" );

test( "hello/.world", ".hpp", "hello/.world.hpp" );
test( "hello/.world", "hpp",  "hello/.world.hpp" );
test( "hello/.world", ".",    "hello/.world." );
test( "hello/.world", "",     "hello/.world" );

test( "hello/w.c", ".hpp", "hello/w.hpp" );
test( "hello/w.c", "hpp",  "hello/w.hpp" );
test( "hello/w.c", ".",    "hello/w." );
test( "hello/w.c", "",     "hello/w" );

test( "hello/w..c", ".hpp", "hello/w..hpp" );
test( "hello/w..c", "hpp",  "hello/w..hpp" );
test( "hello/w..c", ".",    "hello/w.." );
test( "hello/w..c", "",     "hello/w." );

test( "hello/.w.c", ".hpp", "hello/.w.hpp" );
test( "hello/.w.c", "hpp",  "hello/.w.hpp" );
test( "hello/.w.c", ".",    "hello/.w." );
test( "hello/.w.c", "",     "hello/.w" );

test( "hello/.w..", ".hpp", "hello/.w..hpp" );
test( "hello/.w..", "hpp",  "hello/.w..hpp" );
test( "hello/.w..", ".",    "hello/.w.." );
test( "hello/.w..", "",     "hello/.w." );

test( "hello/.w.", ".hpp", "hello/.w.hpp" );
test( "hello/.w.", "hpp",  "hello/.w.hpp" );
test( "hello/.w.", ".",    "hello/.w." );
test( "hello/.w.", "",     "hello/.w" );

test( "hello/.w", ".hpp", "hello/.w.hpp" );
test( "hello/.w", "hpp",  "hello/.w.hpp" );
test( "hello/.w", ".",    "hello/.w." );
test( "hello/.w", "",     "hello/.w" );

test( "hello/...", ".hpp", "hello/...hpp" );
test( "hello/...", "hpp",  "hello/...hpp" );
test( "hello/...", ".",    "hello/..." );
test( "hello/...", "",     "hello/.." );

test( "hello/..", ".hpp", "hello/.." );
test( "hello/..", "hpp",  "hello/.." );
test( "hello/..", ".",    "hello/.." );
test( "hello/..", "",     "hello/.." );

test( "hello/.", ".hpp", "hello/." );
test( "hello/.", "hpp",  "hello/." );
test( "hello/.", ".",    "hello/." );
test( "hello/.", "",     "hello/." );

test( "hello/", ".hpp", "hello/" );
test( "hello/", "hpp",  "hello/" );
test( "hello/", ".",    "hello/" );
test( "hello/", "",     "hello/" );

test( "wor.ld.c", ".hpp", "wor.ld.hpp" );
test( "wor.ld.c", "hpp",  "wor.ld.hpp" );
test( "wor.ld.c", ".",    "wor.ld." );
test( "wor.ld.c", "",     "wor.ld" );

test( "world..c", ".hpp", "world..hpp" );
test( "world..c", "hpp",  "world..hpp" );
test( "world..c", ".",    "world.." );
test( "world..c", "",     "world." );

test( "world.c", ".hpp", "world.hpp" );
test( "world.c", "hpp",  "world.hpp" );
test( "world.c", ".",    "world." );
test( "world.c", "",     "world" );

test( "world..", ".hpp", "world..hpp" );
test( "world..", "hpp",  "world..hpp" );
test( "world..", ".",    "world.." );
test( "world..", "",     "world." );

test( "world.", ".hpp", "world.hpp" );
test( "world.", "hpp",  "world.hpp" );
test( "world.", ".",    "world." );
test( "world.", "",     "world" );

test( "world", ".hpp", "world.hpp" );
test( "world", "hpp",  "world.hpp" );
test( "world", ".",    "world." );
test( "world", "",     "world" );

test( ".wor.ld.c", ".hpp", ".wor.ld.hpp" );
test( ".wor.ld.c", "hpp",  ".wor.ld.hpp" );
test( ".wor.ld.c", ".",    ".wor.ld." );
test( ".wor.ld.c", "",     ".wor.ld" );

test( ".world..c", ".hpp", ".world..hpp" );
test( ".world..c", "hpp",  ".world..hpp" );
test( ".world..c", ".",    ".world.." );
test( ".world..c", "",     ".world." );

test( ".world.c", ".hpp", ".world.hpp" );
test( ".world.c", "hpp",  ".world.hpp" );
test( ".world.c", ".",    ".world." );
test( ".world.c", "",     ".world" );

test( ".world..", ".hpp", ".world..hpp" );
test( ".world..", "hpp",  ".world..hpp" );
test( ".world..", ".",    ".world.." );
test( ".world..", "",     ".world." );

test( ".world.", ".hpp", ".world.hpp" );
test( ".world.", "hpp",  ".world.hpp" );
test( ".world.", ".",    ".world." );
test( ".world.", "",     ".world" );

test( ".world", ".hpp", ".world.hpp" );
test( ".world", "hpp",  ".world.hpp" );
test( ".world", ".",    ".world." );
test( ".world", "",     ".world" );

test( "w.c", ".hpp", "w.hpp" );
test( "w.c", "hpp",  "w.hpp" );
test( "w.c", ".",    "w." );
test( "w.c", "",     "w" );

test( "w..c", ".hpp", "w..hpp" );
test( "w..c", "hpp",  "w..hpp" );
test( "w..c", ".",    "w.." );
test( "w..c", "",     "w." );

test( ".w.c", ".hpp", ".w.hpp" );
test( ".w.c", "hpp",  ".w.hpp" );
test( ".w.c", ".",    ".w." );
test( ".w.c", "",     ".w" );

test( ".w..", ".hpp", ".w..hpp" );
test( ".w..", "hpp",  ".w..hpp" );
test( ".w..", ".",    ".w.." );
test( ".w..", "",     ".w." );

test( ".w.", ".hpp", ".w.hpp" );
test( ".w.", "hpp",  ".w.hpp" );
test( ".w.", ".",    ".w." );
test( ".w.", "",     ".w" );

test( ".w", ".hpp", ".w.hpp" );
test( ".w", "hpp",  ".w.hpp" );
test( ".w", ".",    ".w." );
test( ".w", "",     ".w" );

test( "...", ".hpp", "...hpp" );
test( "...", "hpp",  "...hpp" );
test( "...", ".",    "..." );
test( "...", "",     ".." );

test( "..", ".hpp", ".." );
test( "..", "hpp",  ".." );
test( "..", ".",    ".." );
test( "..", "",     ".." );

test( ".", ".hpp", "." );
test( ".", "hpp",  "." );
test( ".", ".",    "." );
test( ".", "",     "." );

test( "", ".hpp", "" );
test( "", "hpp",  "" );
test( "", ".",    "" );
test( "", "",     "" );

I’m sure if I have missed anything I’ll hear it again. Commenters may not always be nice about it, but they really are interested in good code and good answers.
going forward
The way quality path handling routines usually work is to first separate a path into its component parts, and then play with things like filename and extension. This code kind of jumps the gun and does both at once. A more robust routine to separate path components would make this so much cleaner.
Is this all overload? Yeah, it is. Because playing with strings in C is not as easy as it looks like it ought to be. If you want to do anything useful with C, there is always a bit of a framework you need to build up to do it well — which is, correctly and readably.

This doesn't identify the issues with the OP's code and thus is a poor answer.

*"Tested thoroughly."  I would rather say poorly. https://godbolt.org/z/af76dacq7

(*extension and (*extension != '.')) woudln't even compile
